# How to convert an audio file in colab to text?

Tags: python-3.x, google-colaboratory

I am trying to convert an audio file I have in colab workspace into text using the speech recognition module. But it doesn't work as the audio argument here needs to be audio, how do I load an audio file "audio.wav" into some variable to pass there or just simply pass that file.

```
import speech_recognition as sr
r = sr.Recognizer()
text = r.recognize_google(audio, language = 'en-IN')
print(text)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `speech_recognition` library has a procedure to read in audio files. You can do:

```
inp = sr.AudioFile('path/to/audio/file')
with inp as file:
  audio = r.record(file)
```

After that pass the `audio` as the first argument to `r.recognize_google()`

[Here](https://realpython.com/python-speech-recognition/#using-record-to-capture-data-from-a-file) is a good article to understand this library.

Comment: I tried but i get this error:

ValueError: Audio file could not be read as PCM WAV, AIFF/AIFF-C, or Native FLAC; check if the file is corrupted or in another format. Even though I tried with  wav and mp3 both.

Comment: The file might be corrupted, are you able to open and listen to the file on your system?

Comment: It work's thank you, but it's not converting the text correct. Like the audio says:

"What type of cloth is this" But it only gives the text "What" , it seems to work fine on my python env in windows but not on colab.

Answer (score 0):

```
pip3 install SpeechRecognition pydub
```

Make sure you have an audio file in the current directory that contains english speech

```
import speech_recognition as sr

filename = "16-122828-0002.wav"
```

The below code is responsible for loading the audio file, and converting the speech into text using Google Speech Recognition:

```
# initialize the recognizer
r = sr.Recognizer()

# open the file
with sr.AudioFile(filename) as source:
    # listen for the data (load audio to memory)
    audio_data = r.record(source)
    # recognize (convert from speech to text)
    text = r.recognize_google(audio_data)
    print(text)
```

This will take few seconds to finish, as it uploads the file to Google and grabs the output